# How can I use php to remove tags with empty text node?

Tags: php, html, tags, textnode

How can I use php to remove tags with empty text node?

For instance,

`<div class="box"></div>` remove

`<a href="#"></a>` remove

`<p><a href="#"></a></p>` remove

`<span style="..."></span>` remove

But I want to keep the tag with text node like this,

`<a href="#">link</a>` keep

**Edit:**

I want to remove something messy like this too,

```
<p><strong><a href="http://xx.org.uk/dartmoor-arts"></a></strong></p>
<p><strong><a href="http://xx.org.uk/depw"></a></strong></p>
<p><strong><a href="http://xx.org.uk/devon-guild-of-craftsmen"></a></strong></p>
```

I tested both regex below,

```
$content = preg_replace('!<(.*?)[^>]*>\s*</\1>!','',$content);
$content = preg_replace('%<(.*?)[^>]*>\\s*</\\1>%', '', $content);
```

But they leave something like this,

```
<p><strong></strong></p>
<p><strong></strong></p>
<p><strong></strong></p>
```

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: Your forgot empty elements `<a href="http://xx.org.uk/depw" />`. You should parse the document instead of regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml(
    '<p><strong><a href="http://xx.org.uk/dartmoor-arts">test</a></strong></p>
    <p><strong><a href="http://xx.org.uk/depw"></a></strong></p>
    <p><strong><a href="http://xx.org.uk/devon-guild-of-craftsmen"></a></strong></p>'
);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

while(($nodeList = $xpath->query('//*[not(text()) and not(node())]')) && $nodeList->length > 0) {
    foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

Probably you'll have to change that a bit for your needs.

Comment: thank you! it works! but I dont quite understand the code with `do()` or `while()`. is it possible to write it in `for()`? thanks.

Comment: @lauthiamkok - the while loop is needed so that *newly created empty tags* get removed to. This is because, after (for example) removing an a-tag the wrapping strong-tag becomes empty, but that strong-tag will not be removed on the first iteration. So the `foreach` removes the found nodes, and the `while` loop runs as long there are are empty nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a regex replace like:

```
$updated="";
while($updated != $original) {
    $updated = $original;
    $original = preg_replace('!<(.*?)[^>]*>\s*</\1>!','',$updated);
}
```

Putting it in a while loop should fix it.

Comment: thanks. but it does not remove the tags entirely... please see my edit above. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should buffer the PHP output, then parse that output with some regex, like this:

```
// start buffering output
ob_start();
// do some output
echo '<div id="non-empty">I am not empty</div><a class="empty"></a>';
// at this point you want to output the contents to the client
$contents = ob_get_contents();
// end buffering and flush
ob_end_flush();
// replace empty html tags
$contents = preg_replace('%<(.*?)[^>]*>\\s*</\\1>%', '', $contents);
// echo the sanitized contents
echo $contents;
```

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: thanks Tom, but it has the problem like Chiby's answer - it does not remove the messy tags in my edit above. please have a look. thanks.