# DOM parser: remove tags of empty text node Vs <br/>

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

I have this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801586/how-can-i-use-php-to-remove-tags-with-empty-text-node) earlier regarding removing the html tags that have empty text node.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml(
    '<p><strong><a href="http://xx.org.uk/dartmoor-arts">test</a></strong></p>
    <p><strong><a href="http://xx.org.uk/depw"></a></strong></p>
    <p><strong><a href="http://xx.org.uk/devon-guild-of-craftsmen"></a></strong></p>
    <p>this line has a <br/>break</p>
    '
);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);


while(($nodeList = $xpath->query('//*[not(text()) and not(node())]')) && $nodeList->length > 0) {
    foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
}


echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

it works perfectly but I don't want it to remove `<br/>` tag - how can I keep it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this XPath (it excludes `br` nodes):

```
//*[not(text() or node() or self::br)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just test the `$node` before removal, like:

```
if (!in_array($node->nodeName, array('br'))) {  // add further nodes to keep
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try replacing your `<br/>` tags with something like `[br/]` and then restoring them after.

Easy enough trick :)

Comment: this is not a good practice and creates more work than necessary